# Jquery Default Selection on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, filter

I've set up a custom google maps with custom image with filter options.
The filter options get triggered when the input of

```
 <form id="sizer" action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" value="1">
   <select id="selector">
    <option value="1">Khenarthis Roost</option>
  </select>
```

gets changed.

Checkboxes for filtering: (1 example)

```
<fieldset class="option1">
<img src="http://www.budget-computing.nl/images/teso/markers/city.png">
       <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-01"><input name="checkbox-01" id="checkbox-1" value="1" type="checkbox"  /> City</label></fieldset>
```

For this specific one it is required to load that value on pageload so it gets redirected directly and the markers get loaded. To load the coordinates and map markers it requires to have atleast 2 options and it gets changed when you pick one. At page load it loads nothing. I've tested it with multiple options and that works like a charm. But in this specific case i only want it to be able to show this option and loads it on pageload. The code for the coordination redirecting and loading markers is in here:

```
<script>
function initialize() {



  var mapOptions = {
    center: mapcenter,
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 6,
    draggable: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ["map"]
    },
    panControl: false,
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_Left
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_Center
}
  };

  var iconBase = 'http://www.budget-computing.nl/images/teso/markers/';


  //select the sizer here
        var sizer=$('#sizer input:checkbox');

// Attach the map to the document
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

          // hide the fieldsets on page load
          $(".option1").hide();
          // Connect the group of checkboxes to the select

          $("select").change(function() {
            var $this = $(this);


            if($this.val() === "1") {

                    // Link checkbox markers

                        sizer.change(function(e){
                          var props=0;

                          $.each(sizer,function(i,b){
                              props+=($(b).is(':checked'))?Math.pow(2,i):0;
                            });

                          for(var m=0; m < markers1.length; m++){
                              markers1[m].setMap((props & markers1[m].props ||!props)?map: null);


                          }


                        }).eq(0).trigger('change');

                      // Removing all the markers

                     for (i=0; i< markers1.length; i++) {
                            markers1[i].setMap(null)
                          }

                      $(".option1").show();
                      newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-47,0);
                      map.setZoom(6);

                  setTimeout(function() {

                      markers1=[new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[0],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'camp.png',
                          props: 4,
                          title: 'marker1'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[1],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'city.png',
                          props: 1,
                          title: 'marker2'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[2],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'wayshrine.png',
                          props: 2,
                          title: 'marker3'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[3],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'wayshrine.png',
                          props: 2,
                          title: 'marker4'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[4],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'poi.png',
                          props: 8,
                          title: 'marker5'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[5],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'poi.png',
                          props: 8,
                         title: 'marker6'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[6],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'poi.png',
                          props: 8,
                          title: 'marker7'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[7],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'poi.png',
                          props: 8,
                         title: 'marker8'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[8],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'poi.png',
                          props: 8,
                         title: 'marker9'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[9],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'cave.png',
                          props: 64,
                         title: 'marker10'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[10],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'castleruin.png',
                          props: 128,
                         title: 'marker11'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[11],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'farm.png',
                          props: 16,
                         title: 'marker12'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[12],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'farm.png',
                          props: 16,
                         title: 'marker13'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[13],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'farm.png',
                          props: 16,
                         title: 'marker14'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[14],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'harbor.png',
                          props: 32,
                         title: 'marker15'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[15],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'harbor.png',
                          props: 32,
                         title: 'marker16'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[16],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker17'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[17],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker18'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[18],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker19'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[19],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker20'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[20],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker21'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[21],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker22'
                      }),new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: positions1[22],
                          map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'skyshard.png',
                          props: 256,
                         title: 'marker23'
                    })];

                          },800)
            } 

             map.panTo(newPos);

          });


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('map', mapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('map');
  map.setZoom(1);


markers1=[],
numProps=8;   // The number of the groups


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I've added only 1 out of many markers in this page and the coorinates are loaded by script. Dont worry by that.

My question is: How can i make this code load Khenarthis Roost with option value="1" coordinates and markers on pageload.

Comment: It would be easier to give an answer when you post the complete script

Comment: Alright. I edited the last script

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to trigger the change-event for the select:

```
      $("select").change(function() {
        //your code           
      }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Which part of my code do you mean with // your code?

Comment: there is only 1 part in your code that starts with`$("select").change(function() {`